# pybind11 module not finding dlls (InportError)

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Mighty Gods of Stackoverflow,

I've wondered enought in the pits of pybind11 to make me ask for help. I'm trying to build a python module to encapsulate a small lib a compiled in VS, using three libraries (QuantLib/Ext and LIBPQXX). The library builds fine in VS.

I followed the instructions pybind11's site and also building using the `python setup.py build` everything works fine.

The thing is that when I try to run the installed module in python I get an ImportError saying a DLL can't be found. For some unknown reason, building the module with a conda enviroment that I have, with many other unrelated modules installed, works. But when I try to build it with a new enviroment (in a different python version), fails.

The first thing I did was using a dependency walker to get a peak into de .pyd file, but I think most of these files are found when the module is run in the conda envieroment since conda adds some paths to the PATH env variable that have thouse dlls:

[image]

Then, I thought that maybe the problem was that `setup.py` was changing the name of the module (the name of the module should be `curvemanager`), and that was the reason why it worked in the old conda envieroment (py37) and not in the new one (py310):

[image]

So I changed the file's names manually but it didn't work.

Lastly, I tried moving some dlls manually. I know that LIBPQXX uses some dlls in order to run, but I pasted all of them in the folder with no luck.

I'm running out of ideas, so any help is very appreciated.

EDIT:
Added the setup.py file as requested.

```
    # Available at setup time due to pyproject.toml
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext
from setuptools import setup

from pathlib import Path
__version__ = "0.0.1"

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).absolute().parent.parent.parent.parent.resolve()
print(BASE_DIR)
ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension("curvemanager",
        ["module.cpp"],
        include_dirs=[str(BASE_DIR / 'curvemanager/curvemanager'),
                      str(BASE_DIR / 'repos/libpqxx/libpqxx/Release/include'),
                      str(BASE_DIR / 'repos/Engine/QuantLib'),
                      str(BASE_DIR / 'repos/Engine/QuantExt'),
                      str(BASE_DIR / 'repos/boost')],
        library_dirs=[str(BASE_DIR / 'repos/libpqxx/libpqxx/Release/lib'),
                      str(BASE_DIR / 'repos/Engine/QuantLib/lib'),
                      str(BASE_DIR / 'repos/Engine/QuantExt/lib'),
                      str(BASE_DIR / 'repos/boost/libs'),
                      str(BASE_DIR / 'curvemanager/build/x64/Release'),],
        libraries=['libpq','pqxx', 'QuantLib-x64-mt', 'QuantExt-x64-mt','wsock32','ws2_32','curvemanager'],
        # Example: passing in the version to the compiled code
        define_macros = [('VERSION_INFO', __version__)],
        extra_compile_args=['-std=c++20', '-O3','-Fe curvemanager.pyd'],
        ),
]

setup(
    name="curvemanager",
    version=__version__,      
    description="curvemanager using pybind11",
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    include_package_data=True,
    data_files=[("", ["libpq.dll"])],
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    zip_safe=False,
    python_requires=">=3.7",
)
```

Comment: Could I see your `setup.py` file?

Comment: Sure!, I added a  snippet.